# How to add vertical space after the recipient's address in a letter?

Tags: letters, lettre

I have written a letter.
My problem is I don't know how to add a vertical space *only* between the recipient's address and \conc.

If I put `vspace*{2cm}`, the vertical space is add on the first line of the letter, before the sender's address.

If I add `\setlength\openingspace{2cm}` , a space is added between the recipient's address and the concname (it's ok) but also between the concname and the opening.

I would like only to shift all that is after the recipient's address.

Do you know how can I do?

Thank you so much!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{lettre}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\institut{sender}

%\setlength\openingspace{2cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
\vspace{0.75cm}

My company

46, avenue de Provence

75009 Paris
}

\conc{Bla bla}
\renewcommand{\nrefname}{}
%\nref{}%Références de la lettre, de votre point de vue}

\opening{Madame, Monsieur,}

Big bla bla bla etc.

\closing{Je vous prie d'agréer, Madame, Monsieur, l'assurance de ma parfaite considération.}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The institut file (for the to-adress) is "sender.ins". The code is below:

```
\name{Paul Arthur}

\address{%
Paul Arthur

My company

12 rue du paradis

31000 Toulouse
}

%\telephone{05 00 00 00 00}
\notelephone

%\email{paul.arthur@nomail.fr}
\nofax %c'est \fax{} pour indiquer un numéro de fax

% Ce paramètre sert à indiquer dans la lettre « Paris, le »
\lieu{Toulouse}

\signature{Paul Arthur}

%Pour supprimer le trait de pliage à gauche
\renewcommand*{\rule@length}{0}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for adding an example document. As posted, however, it doesn't compile without errors and requires some external file. You can add external file(s) to the document using `\begin{filecontents}{<filename>} ... \end{filecontents}`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the institut file's code. It can compile now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `etoolbox` package to patch the `\concdecl` command and add the space directly to it.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\concdecl}{\vspace*{2cm}}{}{}
```

Here's a complete document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{lettre}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\concdecl}{\vspace*{2cm}}{}{}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.ins}
\name{Paul Arthur}
\address{%
Paul Arthur

My company

12 rue du paradis

31000 Toulouse
}

%\telephone{05 00 00 00 00}
\notelephone

%\email{paul.arthur@nomail.fr}
\nofax %c'est \fax{} pour indiquer un numéro de fax

% Ce paramètre sert à indiquer dans la lettre « Paris, le »
\lieu{Toulouse}

\signature{Paul Arthur}

%Pour supprimer le trait de pliage à gauche
\renewcommand*{\rule@length}{0}
\end{filecontents}

\institut{foo}

%\setlength\openingspace{2cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
\vspace{0.75cm}

My company

46, avenue de Provence

75009 Paris
}
\conc{Bla bla}
\renewcommand{\nrefname}{}
%\nref{}%Références de la lettre, de votre point de vue}

\opening{Madame, Monsieur,}

Big bla bla bla etc.

\closing{Je vous prie d'agréer, Madame, Monsieur, l'assurance de ma parfaite considération.}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this code adds a vertical space on the top of the page, between the border and the first row of the sender's adress.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see any differences when I change the length in \vspace*{2cm} or, even, when I comment the line. Maybe we haven't the same configuration. However the package etoolbox is installed; so I don't understand.

Comment: I successed when I changed `\concdecl`  from your code to `\concline`. So the solution is `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\concline}{\vspace*{2cm}}{}{}` . Thank you so much! I would never have found it alone.